# Advanced Filter exact match

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am using Advanced Filter to organize a dataset. For the name criteria, if I search "ABC" it will include names such as "ABCD". How do I prevent this and only return an exact matche?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of ABC in advanced criteria write :
`="=ABC"`

**Before Filter**

[image]

**After applying advanced filter**

[image]

A good place to learn Advanced Filter click on the link  http://www.contextures.com/xladvfilter01.html